# APN Database in different Windows Versions

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, windows-8

I have 3 questions :

1. Windows 8 contains APN Database file which is being used for connectivity configuration. Windows 8.1 probably has one too. Is there any difference between those two files ?
2. Does Windows Phone 8 contain APN Database file too and if yes what is the difference between that file and the files in Windows 8 / 8.1 ?
3. How can I see/list on my computer all APNs (or APN Database file) contained in my Windows phone in a easy way ?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I always thought the APN settings were pushed either by the SIM, or the network - what make you think these are preloaded in the OS?

Comment: The .xml file containing APN configurations for big part of the networks in the world.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: windows 8 / system32 / apndatabase.xml

Answer (score 1):

There is no access to the operating system files on a Windows Phone, this means that even if it is there (and not cut down for an operator specific model), it is not accessible by an end user, as it is not exposed as a browsable list in the settings.